# What is the API parameter for reach of a post in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

While using an FQL query to get likes on posts of a particular page ,we use the following code

```
SELECT post_id, like_info.like_count 
FROM stream WHERE source_id = *Page ID*
```

While in graph API we use

```
9085937115/feed?fields=likes
```

How do we to get to know the "reach" of a particular picture.
A picture has its own likes,comments,shares and "reach"

I've tried searching the docs but in vain.I have also tried bluntly replacing likes with reach,but with no result.

Can anyone please help me in finding the parameter for reach of particular post.Thanks

Comment: To the person who gave me a downvote,any reasons?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is an **insight**, so if you want to know the reach of a particular post you have to do this:

```
/POST_ID/insights
```

This will return a lot of insights you just have to narrow, to the one you want, in this case you have 7 options that may suit to you:

1. **Lifetime Post Total Reach**
2. **Lifetime Post Paid Reach**
3. **Lifetime Post organic reach**
4. **Lifetime Post viral reach**
5. **Lifetime Post viral reach by story type**
6. **Lifetime Post reach by people who like your Page**
7. **Lifetime Paid reach of a post by people who like your Page**

The insights metric is available in 4 ways:

1. `/{page-id}/insights`
2. `/{app-id}/insights`
3. `/{domain-id}/insights`
4. `/{post-id}/insights (where this is a Page post)`

You can read more about insights metrics here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights

Comment: Can we see the number of shares too?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid anymore. I'm getting "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"